# Unity TextMesh Pro how to remove random floating lines from text

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm working with Unity and TextMesh Pro to make a menu for my game, and I keep getting these random lines on all of my text. (see image)

[Random line image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4tgf.png)

I'm using Roboto bold as my font, I imported it into unity and converted it to a TMP Font Asset, if it helps. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome Bob333, I am struggling to see why your question should get a down vote. A little bit more detail would of helped, however, from my point of view this question is clear enough so  I'll upvote you. Enjoy Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the generated `SDF` file in your project, then find the subheader setting called `Generation Settings`. Your `Padding` should be about `1/10th` of your `Sampling Point Size`. [image: Example]

As you see in my example text, the `Sampling Point Size` was generated to be about 116 when imported, so I set the `Padding` to be 12, or roughly 10% of the `Sampling Point Size`. I would mess around with the `Padding` number until you are happy with the results.

Comment: Additional Note: You have to set Atlas population mode to Dynamic. And If your text become blurry after applying with 1/10 padding, try increasing atlas width and height.